# I cannot obtain the rpm of ContextBroker

Tags: jenkins, makefile, rpm, fiware-orion

I have tried to obtain the rpm associated to ContextBroker component (https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion.git) but I have obtained the following error after executing `make rpm`.

```
 [ 98%] Building CXX object src/lib/mongoBackend/CMakeFiles/mongoBackend.dir/mongoNotifyContextAvailability.cpp.o
 Linking CXX static library libmongoBackend.a
 make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/develenv/app/jenkins/config-history/jobs/ContextBroker-Build/fiware-orion/rpm/BUILD/contextBroker-0.14.1_next/BUILD_RELEASE'
 [ 98%] Built target mongoBackend
 make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/develenv/app/jenkins/config-history/jobs/ContextBroker-Build/fiware-orion/rpm/BUILD/contextBroker-0.14.1_next/BUILD_RELEASE'
 make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
 make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/develenv/app/jenkins/config-history/jobs/ContextBroker-Build/fiware-orion/rpm/BUILD/contextBroker-0.14.1_next/BUILD_RELEASE'
 make[1]: *** [release] Error 2
 make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/develenv/app/jenkins/config-history/jobs/ContextBroker-Build/fiware-orion/rpm/BUILD/contextBroker-0.14.1_next'
 error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.NPtnCN (%build)
 RPM build errors:
     Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.NPtnCN (%build)
 make: *** [rpm] Error 1
```

Previously to this stage I compiled and executed the unit tests as well as functional tests with no problems I am working on Red Hat 4.4.7-3 with repo/branch:

https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/tree/release/iotplatform-v1

Thanks for your help

UPDATE:
The linux distribution used was CentOS 6.4

Comment: Maybe [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) is the better place. There is no code, but what does `/var/tmp/rpm-tmp.NPtnCN` contain?

Comment: OS requirements for Orion Context Broker are CentOS/RedHat 6.3 or newer (see [requirements](https://forge.fi-ware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_Installation_and_Administration_Guide#Requirements)). Could you test in RedHat 6.3 and report the result as an update in the question post, please?

Comment: Sorry, misunderstanding, the linux distro where the error happened was CentOS 6.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problems is solved if you install cantcoap and COAP client, as described in [the Orion README.md file](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/blob/develop/README.md), then execute `make rpm`.

Note that although COAP stuff is optional to build the code itself with `make release` or `make debug` the RPM building target needs them by the time being (we probably fix this in the future).

**UPDATE:** the fix of the RPM makefile target is being dealed at this Github.com issue: https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/579